# which one should we choose of the original url and 'Data URLs' when drawing the image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have code in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewGong/mkx7f8un/11/):

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
src="https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/3D-High-Resolution-Images-620x349.jpg"

var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";  
image.onload = function(){
  var imgWidth=image.width;
  var imgHeight=image.height;

  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);  
}
image.src = src
```

I find sometime when I use the url of a web image, it works. But sometime I must use the 'Data URLs' of a web image. So which one should we choose in general? the original url or Data URLs?

Can anyone give some advises?

Comment: I suspect the difference isn't resolution, but *origin*. The Same Origin Policy limits what you can do with images from other origins. See "Using Images from Other Domains" (they mean origins) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images).

Comment: setting crossorigin attribute to anonymous results in `A cross-origin request (i.e., with Origin: HTTP header) is performed. But no credential is sent (i.e., no cookie, no X.509 certificate, and no HTTP Basic authentication is sent).` **`If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (by not setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted.`**

Comment: but how to create a 'Data URLs' for the url image

Answer (score 0):

This is because you retrieve the image from an external server. try to convert images from the same server as yours, or convert the image to base64. you find on the Internet several sites to convert an image to base6

example : `src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZg.......DEFF";`

Comment: but how to create a 'Data URLs' for the url image?

Comment: I mean how to create a 'Data URLs' for the url image.

Answer (score 0):

It is not depends of picture size - it is Cross domain request browser restriction. You can't retrieve http resources from another domain without special HTTP header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in a response.
You can find more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the problem resides in CORS permissions. Basically the browser will not allow you to load up the contents of an image hosted on an external server (unless it has explicit CORS permissions to do so). Sometimes setting crossOrigin to anonymous solves it but in most cases it won't.

The only way to solve this problem is to do a cURL request to the image, download it to your server and then use it.

Usually you will only need DataURLs (base64 encoded images) when exporting the image from the canvas - using toDataURL() although, if you do make a cURL request and don't want to keep the physical image on your server you can just base64encode the response and load it on your canvas as a base64 DataURL.